# How to load SVF to Autodeks Forge viewer Offline in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load SVF file on Autodesk forge viewer locally in Xamarin.Android. I copied the [content](https://github.com/adamenagy/android-offline-viewer/tree/master/app/src/main/assets/html) to my project Assets/html folder. My code to load the content looks like this.

In MyWebViewClient.cs

```
 public WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView webView, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            Android.Net.Uri url = request.Url;
            //Uri uri = url;
            String path = url.Path;
            if (path.StartsWith("/android_asset/"))
            {
                try
                {
                    AssetManager assetManager = this.context.Assets;
                    String relPath = path.Replace("/android_asset/", "").Replace("gz", "gz.mp3");
                    //InputStream stream = assetManager.Open(relPath);
                    return new WebResourceResponse(null, null, assetManager.Open(relPath));
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    String str = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        return null;
    }
```

Then in my Activity.cs

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.webview);
 var wbMain = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
 wbMain.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
 wbMain.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
 wbMain.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
 wbMain.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
 var customWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient(BaseContext);
 customWebViewClient.OnPageLoaded += MyWebViewClient_OnPageLoaded;

 wbMain.SetWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
 wbMain.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

This only loads the side views not the main viewer.
[image]

Whats the reason for this and how can I resolve this?

Comment: The last time I tried to do this it wasn't working... So whenever you do find a solution please share it here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the sample is a bit outdated and there have been some changes in our legal terms since then. Currently, the legal T&C state that all viewer assets (JS, CSS, icons, images, etc.) *must* be coming from the Autodesk domain.

If you need to be able to run your viewer-based app in "temporarily offline" scenarios (for example, on a construction site), I'd suggest that you look at the following blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows. This approach (using Service Workers and Cache API) is consistent with the legal requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to successfully run https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-disconnected on my laptop and now I need to convert this into Xamarin.android. Is it still doable adding the content of this project under Assets/html folder in my Xamarin.Android project? How can we do this on Android or iOS? could you provide some guidance?

Comment: You should not be storing any of the viewer assets in your project's folder. The idea of the "temporarily offline" approach is that the viewer assets are cached by the browser but still linked to their original domain.

Comment: In other words, you can run your viewer application in the "temporarily offline" mode in a browser, but not in a custom app that would require downloading any of the viewer assets.